# Is there a way to set a geometry filter on a esri.layers.FeatureLayer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Suppose I want to limit the extent of a feature layer to a geometry (say a circle).  Is that possible?

I am aware of setDefinitionExpression but that is limited to a attribute filter.  There seems to be nothing like a setGeometryFilter.

If not it would be nice to get a "before-apply-filter" event where we could modify the underlying query.

Comment: esriCarto.ILayerMasking?

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#queryextent (but only works for arcgisonline?)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the mode of the feature layer to `MODE_SELECTION` and then call [`selectFeatures`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#selectfeatures) method since this takes a `Query` input and you can set the spatial filter on that so that only the features for a particular geometry are returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be very useful but as far as I am aware there is nothing available at present (version 3.8).

The only way I can think to do this is not the best and there are limitations to it. You could perform a queryTask and [executeforids](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/querytask-amd.html#executeforids) which will return more than 1000 features (i.e. it is not limited like the query task by the server). You can then use these id's along with a definition query on the layer. Assuming you are using an FGDB the best I can find is that a definition query is [limited to 30,000 characters](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=218219), although suggests it may be more. However, unless you are using a proxy it will be limited to [2000 characters](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html#setlayerdefinitions) (browser dependent). I have no idea what the performance of this will be like.

I'd suggest that if this is likely to be used regularly you look into setting up a geoprocessing service which [creates a result map service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_result_map_services_in_REST_applications/0057000000m6000000/).

I would be interested to hear your findings

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but an idea is to create the feature layer from a [feature collection](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#featurelayer2), and base the collection on the result of a queryTask, since the queryTask's query does support a [geometry filter](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html#geometry).